# Why can't I buy Unicoins?

Tags: support

Every time I click on an option it is not accepted, what option should I choose to buy some unicoins?

I really like the effect.

Comment: It's a known issue.  You have to post your credit card over in mother meta for them to process the transaction.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Unicoins.

Comment: But what aren't unicoins a part of the stackexchange network?

Comment: @BrandonEnright this is a serious question why can't I buy them with my reputation points?

Comment: @BrandonEnright I disagree, this is a perfectly on-topic question about a startling new site feature.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about unicoins

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unicoins are at present functional in certain features of the site. You can obtain them by mining them on the same applet window where you can spend them:

[image]

Unfortunately, it appears most monetary means to obtain Unicoins are taking some time to go online. That means that at present there is no way to obtain them other than mining. If you feel strongly about it, there are ways to automate the mining so that your browser will do the work for you!

For more information about Unicoins in general, as well as said automation methods, see the Meta StackOverflow question  [What are Stack Overflow unicoins?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227363/what-are-stack-overflow-unicoins). I should also mention that if you like Unicoins you should hurry to make the best of them, as certain commentators have hinted that this feature [may be available for a limited time only](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_1).